# Comparing columns between two excel file?

Tags: excel

So I have two excel file.

File 1 :

```
A       B     C
M1   -BLANK- New
C3   -BLANK- Old
F35  -BLANK- Old
```

File 2 :

```
A       B      C
M1   -BLANK-   XX
C2   -BLANK-   XX
F35  -BLANK-   XX
```

I would like to compare Column A for the two files, find any corresponding values (M1 and F35) in this case, skip any unmatched values (C3/C2) and write the value from Column C from file 1 to Column B of file 2.

Result:

```
M1    -New-    XX
C2    -BLANK-  XX (Unchanged)
F35   -Old-    XX
```

Any way I can do this?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: What if there's a `C2` further down in file 1? Should the corresponding value of C2 in file 1 column C be written to file 2 next to C2?

Comment: As long any value from column A from file 1 correspond to file 2, the value from file 1 column C should be ported to file 2 column B. So, yes. Sorry I didn't clarify that, thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `VLOOKUP` for this. Assuming that the sheetname in File 1 is called `Sheet1`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet1'!A:C, 3, 0), "")
```

Note: If they are in different workbooks, you might have to put the path of File1 before the sheet name, e.g. if the path is `C:\Workbook.xlsx`, you'll use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'C:\[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C, 3, 0), "")
```

`VLOOKUP` takes the value of A2 in File 2, looks it in the column A of File 2 and returns the value of the third column of the match. It'll return `#N/A` if no match is found, and the `IFERROR` turns any potential `#N/A` into blanks.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I'm a little fuzzy on the last part of the Vlookup command


"'!A:C, 3, 0), "")"


What exactly does 3, 0 specify? The Row number? Also noticed there isn't a  B which strikes me a little odd since I would the C values to go into B. Graci.

Comment: A:C is the lookup table (the lookup table has an index column (the first column, A) and the other columns. I could have used A:D, A:F, etc and it would have still worked). `3` denotes the nth column from which to return the desired value from. So, here, since this is 3, it will return the value from column C (the 3rd column, with A being the first column). `VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet1'!A:C, 2, 0)` would return all blanks because the 2nd column from A (column B) is blank. ``VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet1'!A:C, 4, 0)` will return an error, because the lookup column is 3 columns wide and you are asking a 4th column

Comment: @FrostLeopard You put that formula in cell B2 of File 2 by the way, and copy it down.

Comment: Thanks, really helped. How about rows? Say if i would like to find similar values for two columns then copy entire rows which HAS the same values, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @FrostLeopard Well, entire rows... I would suggest doing a vlookup to identify the rows with the identified values, and use a filter to copy those rows. Then paste in the new file. Otherwise, you'll need a lot of vlookup (which consume a lot of resources on your machine).